# get in Object 'Func with Refinement in Rebol

Tags: rebol

Let's say I have

```
o: context [

  f: func[message /refine message2][
    print [message] 
    if refine [print message 2]
  ]

]
```

I can call it like this

```
do get in o 'f "hello"
```

But how can I do for the refinement ? something like this that would work

```
>> do get in o 'f/refine "hello" "world"
** Script Error: in expected word argument of type: any-word
** Near: do get in o 'f/refine
>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way to directly tell the interpreter to use a refinement in invoking a *function value*.  That would require some parameterization of `do` when its argument is a `function!`  Nothing like that seems to exist...but maybe it's hidden somewhere else.

The only way I know to use a refinement is with a path.  To make it clear, I'll first use a temporary word:

```
>> fword: get in o 'f
>> do compose [(to-path [fword refine]) "hello" "world"]  
hello
world
```

What that second statement evaluates to after the compose is:

```
do [fword/refine "hello" "world"]
```

You can actually put function values into paths too.  It gets rid of the need for the intermediary:

```
>> do compose [(to-path compose [(get in o 'f) refine]) "hello" "world"]
hello
world
```

P.S. you have an extra space between  `message` and `2` above, where it should just be `message2`

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
o/('f)/refine "hello" "world"
```

Parens in a path expression are evaluated if they correspond to object field or series pick/poke index references. That makes the above code equivalent to this:

```
apply get in o 'f ["hello" true "world"]
```

Note that `apply` arguments are positional, so you need to know the order the arguments were declared in. You can't do that trick with the function refinements themselves, so you have to use `apply` or create path expressions to evaluate if you want to parameterize the refinements of the function call.

Answer (score -1):

Use the simple path o/f/refine

Comment: Because I want to call within my new function here http://reboltutorial.com/blog/creating-a-class-based-oop-language-adding-class-constructors-support/ a constructor with a refinement. Since it must apply to any Object, I need to call by variable.

I want to call the constructor automatically.